# How to write text to file using \n and fprintf in C

Tags: c, string, printf, stringbuilder

I am fairly new to C and am struggling when it comes to the concept of string building and how it works. Essentially I am trying to output a report to a .txt document with multiple "/n" new lines.
Here is my string, named s:

```
char buf[256];
int s = sprintf(buf, "Mean %f", a);
s += sprintf(buf+s, " \nMode %i", b);
s += sprintf(buf+s, " \nMedian  %f", c);
s += sprintf(buf+s, " \nStandard Deviation  %f", d);
```

And if I `printf("%s\n", buf);` to console, it works fine.
However, I am trying to write it to a file with the new lines included. Currently when I do this:

```
FILE *file = fopen(filename, mode);
fprintf(file, input);
```

It does not print the new lines, just one long string. What am I doing wrong?

I have looked into it, and found the only solution is to directly print each line to the file i.e

```
fprintf(file, "mean is %f \n", a);
fprintf(file, "mode is %i \n", b);
```

and so on.... I want to avoid this. Any help?

Comment: What is `input` in your second code snippet?  What happens if you just do `fprintf(file, "%s\n", buf)`?

Comment: You're opening `file` with the same mode each time? Immediate guess would be `\r\n` (Microsoft style) versus `\n` (Unix style), and an implementation of `fprintf` that's trying to smooth over the difference. What mode are you supplying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a windows text editor to check the file content, then you need to append `"\r\n"` at the end of the lines.

**As [pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg) commented**: If you open the file with `"w"` mode, that should happen automatically and if it's implemented that way in windows, then it's a better solution because the program will automatically work correctly in another operating system.

Still this seems anoying to me, because the files wouldn't be transferrable across operating systems.

Comment: No! You need to open the file in *text* mode: `fopen(filename, "w")`

Comment: @pmg why, would `fprintf()` add the `'\r'` by itself ? Excuse my ignorance, I don't use windows.

Comment: Because that's the way it's defined to behave ( http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.5.3 ).

Comment: @pmg: yup. Isn't the Magic Mode sequence `"wt"`, though? I.e., is plain `"w"` by default 'text' mode?

Comment: @iharob This is correct, the windows C runtime, in order to make it not break cross platform sources does indeed automatically convert `\n` into `\r\n` when a file is open in text mode. It may actually be better to use this implicit conversion as opposed to an explicit `\r` as it means that if the code is ported to another platform (*nix or mac) it will automatically use the native newline of that platform too.

Comment: No, the `"t"` thing isn't described by the Standard. The absence of `"b"` is enough to determine text-mode translation.

Comment: @Jongware In my experience "w" and "wt" are equivalent, but I use "wt" since it shows some explicit intent versus "oops, I missed something".

Comment: @RetiredNinja: using `"t"` purposefully limits your source to be compiled only on windows.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: thx -- that may also explain why I still use `"wb"`, despite programming on a Mac for several years now :) ("Look mom, I did *not* miss something!")

Comment: The proper paragraph that describes text-mode translation is http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.2

Comment: @pmg I've never run into issues with gcc allowing it even if it is meaningless on a non-windows platform.  *shrug*

Comment: `"wt"` is defined by Microsoft, and it means the same as `"w"` in MSVCRT . In standard C it's undefined behaviour.